# Ajax not working in a jquery split button

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a project in Codeigniter. There is a link

```
<a href="updatearecord/79" class = "orange-red-ui testclass">Edit</a>
```

Clicking on the link will go to the main controller and will execute the function updatearecord. (79 is just an id).

ClientParent is called by a javascript using Ajax call

```
function testfunction() {
$('a.testclass').live('click', function() {
        $url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            data: {},
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'post',
            success: studentSubjectCallBack

        });
```

The link works fine anywhere on the page, but when I use it in a split button, it does not work. Here is the code for the split button

```
<div>
<div>
<a class="split-button"><span class="ui-button-text">Select</a>
<a href="#" class = "orange-red-ui">Menu</a>
</div>
<ul style="display:none;">
<li><a href="#" class = "orange-red-ui deletearecord">Delete</a></li>

<li><a href="updatearecord/%student_id%" class = "orange-red-ui testclass">Edit</a></li>
</ul>

</div>';
```

Can anyone help me out. I really dont understand why it is not working inside a split button

Comment: You are missing the close for span tag inside split button.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel Thanks for pointing it out, but it is still not working

Comment: @DeepakBiswal jquery 1.10

Comment: Please use .on method in place of .live.

`$("body").on('click', '#testclass', function() {
});`

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Yes i understand, but the problem is, it works in the 1st method, but does not work when i use the link inside a split button

Comment: Can you please add your code in jsfiddle, so that I can check it out what exactly your problem is?

Comment: would you mind to create your code in to http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @DeepakBiswal The problem is there are many js files associated with the fucntion, but the essence of the problem is this, ajax return success if the link is used anywhere else, if the link is used inside the split button, ajax returns an error

Comment: split button is on your view from page loading or you are adding it dynamically later to the page?

Comment: It is there from page loading. I am not adding it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have `testclass` assigned to the `a` link in the second example. Your jQuery is looking for this class and can't find any elements that match.

Change:

```
$('a.testclass').live('click', function() {
```

to

```
$('a.editStudentSubject').live('click', function() {
```

As a side note, `.live` is now deprecated as per jQuery 1.7.1. Please use `.on`, such as:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.editStudentSubject', function() {
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i am having testclass instead of editStudentSubject in the second example. But still its not working

Comment: What happens when you do a console.log($url)? Is the click function actually firing?

Comment: yes, the click function is working. I do an alert($url), it is the same for both cases. But ajax returns an error. (ie) in 1st case, seccess : is called, and in 2nd case error: is called

Comment: Ahh, this is actually sounding like an issue from your actual server-side controller then... unless studentSubjectCallBack is missing?

Comment: No, it is not missing. Even if it were missing, it should not have worked in the 1st example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
 <a class="split-button"><span class="ui-button-text">Select</a>
```

Try:

```
  <a class="split-button testclass"><span class="ui-button-text">Select</a>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/leonardeveloper/8vKfb/2/

Comment: What is the version of your jQuery? 
did you try this script?

  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click','.testclass',function(){
     
    alert("working"); 
    return false;
   });

  });

Comment: I use jquery 1.6, so this should not be a problem. Even if it were a problem, it should work if i use the link anywhere. But it does not work only inside the split button

Comment: Oh see. it $(document).on doesn't really work on that version. well then. see: http://jsfiddle.net/8vKfb/4/

Comment: Please do understand my question. The javascript click is happening every time, but the ajax call returns success when used elsewhere and returns error when used inside a split button